# DropBox: How to Fix Stuck Sync?

Tags: windows, dropbox

DropBox syncing has become stuck after I reloaded Windows. It wouldn't budge after hours. Also the system icon kept disappearing, perhaps due to some unreported error. It continually reports it's uploading only 392 file but there's actually one million files to sync (re-index actually). I tried all the solutions on DropBox website and DropBoxForum such as erasing cache, propagating permissions, unlink/relink, reinstalling DropBox, filesystem check/repair, etc. Other computers are syncing properly after a similar reload of Windows. How do I fix sync?

Comment: is it allowed in the fire wall ? Test this by disabling firewall and restarting dropbox and its service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by recopying the DropBox folder from another known working computer. I believe the process worked because it repaired broken files or permissions. Here's the exact steps that I used.

1. Uninstalling DropBox.
2. Reboot.
3. Temporarily disable any backup services such as CrashPlan, Carbonite.
4. Erase DropBox folder.
5. Reboot, keep backup service disabled.
6. Copy contents of DropBox folder from another, properly synced computer.
7. Re-install DropBox.
8. Enable backup service.
9. Wait. On my fast system and internet connection, reindexing performs at a rate of 100,000 files per hour.

Update: I totally gave up on DropBox. It wasn't stable on most of my PCs. I replaced DropBox with an Office 365 subscription (up to six PCs) that included 1TB of OneDrive cloud sync. If you only need Windows cloud sync, OneDrive is a far more robust, and performant. I had no idea how bad DropBox was until I started using OneDrive. OneDrive doesn't chew through CPU and I/O like DropBox.

Comment: These steps may not be necessary. 1) You can try running Dropbox as Administrator to see if sync finishes. 2) If it is stuck on a specific file, use LockHunter (3rd party app) to see what is is using the file. 3) you can also re-do security. command line equivalent is `cacls`. All these steps are worth trying because they will take less time than what you had to do.

Comment: With a dropbox pro subscription, if you know which changes caused the "stuck", then you can remove a folder containing those files locally, then go to dropbox online, find a parent folder of a deleted one, press the "show deleted items" button, select deleted and then "restore" (and, possibly, rewind). Took literally 1 minute for me (small file sizes).